# NextJS How to pass props from pages to components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

My `nextjs`-application has the following folder structure

```
components
  -- layouts
     --- header.tsx
     --- index.tsx
pages
  -- index.tsx
  -- [slug].tsx
```

On my `[slug].tsx` file, I use `graphql` to get data and set the props:

```
export default function Page({ pageData }) {
   const data = pageData.page;
     return (
       <div className="page py-10">
          <h1>{data.title}</h1>
          <p>{data.subtitle}</p>
       </div>
     )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
   const pageRequest = await request({
     query: PAGE_QUERY,
     variables: { slug: params?.slug },
   });

   return {
     props: {
       pageData: pageRequest,
     }
   };
};
```

so far, so good. Now, I want to display the data, in this case the title and the subtitle in the `header.tsx`- file but I was wondering, how to pass the props from a page to a component?

Maybe something like this?

```
export interface IHeader {
   title?: string;
   subtitle?: string;
}

const Header = ({ pageData }: IHeader) => { ... }
```

Is this even possible? If yes, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You sort of answered yourself. It's entirely possible!

This would be a more "correct" way of typing it.

```
export interface IHeader {
   title?: string;
   subtitle?: string;
}

const Header: React.FC<IHeader> = ({ pageData }) => { ... }
```

And in your `Page`:

```
export default function Page({ pageData }) {
   const data = pageData.page;
     return (
       <Header pageData={pageData}/>
     )
}
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion - I want it exactly the other way around: I want the props from the Page to the Header component.... :-)